# How do I prevent a compiler warning when I assign a string literal to static char *argv[]

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm getting the following warning from the compiler

> warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]

for the statement:

```
static char *argv[] = { "pingpong" };
```

In this statement  `argv` can not be a `const` because the function I'm passing it to won't accept it as such.

What would be the correct way to make the assignment without the compiler producing a warning?

Comment: What function are you talking about?

Comment: You could ignore this warning, or turn off `-Wwrite-strings`, or suppress the warning with a cast.  To know whether this is safe or not you'll have to supply more details about the function you are passing it to . Is it possible that that function will try writing to the string?

Comment: @Matt, Our lecturer insists we write code that does not produce warnings.  In fact, our warnings are treated as errors.  So unfortunately that's not an option.  We are developing cross-platform code, and whist it might work on our platform, it might not on another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in pre-C++11 times implicit conversion from string literal (type `const char[*]`) to `char*` was only deprecated, since C++11 that's an error (actually modifying it was UB earlier already).

Create a modifiable array and use that instead, like so:

```
static char argv_0[] = "pingpong";
static char *argv[] = {argv_0};
```

Be aware that the argument to `main` also has a sentinel null-pointer though.

If you are really sure they just got their `const` wrong, explicit casting may work too, though it's a really dirty hack. Better refrain, and clean it up.